# How to make a sticky position for a div inside MUI table container?

Tags: css, material-ui

In **Material UI Table** I have a table applied **sticky property**, which works fine.
 On top of the **table**, but inside the **TableContainer** I have a button wrapped in **Box**, which should also be sticky alongside with the table head. 
 I tried this approach with **flex**, but didn't work for me.

```
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex - direction: column;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.scrollable - child {
   overflow - y: auto;
}
```

Also tried to apply `position: relative` to parent and `position: sticky` to child without success.
Any help will be appreciated.
Here is the [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictable-material-demo-forked-wxqwm?file=/demo.tsx:1643-1670) and code below

```
import * as React from "react";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { Box, Button } from "@mui/material";

function createData(
  name: string,
  calories: number,
  fat: number,
  carbs: number,
  protein: number
) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9)
];

export default function BasicTable() {
  return (
    <TableContainer
      component={Paper}
      sx={{
        maxHeight: "400px",
        minHeight: "400px",
        position: "relative"
      }}
    >
      <Box sx={{ position: "sticky" }}> //this doesn't work
        <Button>click</Button>
      </Box>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table" stickyHeader>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <TableRow
              key={row.name}
              sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
            >
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out how to solve this problem, if anyone else is struggling with a similar issue. 
The way I did, is to do `Column grouping` like described in [MUI Docs](https://mui.com/components/tables/#column-grouping), in other words add my button to a new `TableRow` inside the **Table**.
See working code below and the updated [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictable-material-demo-forked-wxqwm?file=/demo.tsx)

```
import * as React from "react";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { Box, Button } from "@mui/material";

function createData(
  name: string,
  calories: number,
  fat: number,
  carbs: number,
  protein: number
) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9)
];

export default function BasicTable() {
  return (
    <TableContainer
      component={Paper}
      sx={{
        maxHeight: "400px",
        minHeight: "400px"
      }}
    >
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table" stickyHeader>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell colSpan={7}>
              <Button>click</Button>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell style={{ top: 57 }}>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right" style={{ top: 57 }}>
              Calories
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right" style={{ top: 57 }}>
              Fat&nbsp;(g)
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right" style={{ top: 57 }}>
              Carbs&nbsp;(g)
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right" style={{ top: 57 }}>
              Protein&nbsp;(g)
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <TableRow
              key={row.name}
              sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
            >
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to give position: sticky. You need to add coordination info like below.

```
position: sticky;
top: 40px;
left: 40px;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. 
Could you please update the sandbox?
It seems not to work for me with your suggestion.